# Parse in-App-Purchase get price

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, in-app-purchase, price

I'm using Parse for my in-App-Purchases and everything works fine. Now I want to get the price to display it in my app.
I tried this code from their website but I can't find the price variable - only the productidentifier.

```
        let productQuery = PFProduct.query()
        productQuery?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (obj:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
          if let product = obj?.last {
              let prod = product as! PFProduct

              print(prod.productIdentifier, prod.title)
          }
        })
```

So how can I get the price of my in-App-Purchase.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything to get a product's price. When you send a request, it will automatically fetch its price.

Answer (score 0):

For get price of in-app product, you can use my server.
Works only for available apps in the App Store.

Send post request to:

```
http://195.138.193.194:5003/store/
```

With body:

```
{
  "bundleId": "com.example.bundle",
  "products": [
    "com.example.productId1",
    "com.example.productId2",
  ]
}
```